# Spark iterative Kmeans not getting expected results?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, k-means

I am writing a naive implementation of Kmeans in Spark for my homework:

```
import breeze.linalg.{ Vector, DenseVector, squaredDistance }
import scala.math 
def parse(line: String): Vector[Double] = {
    DenseVector(line.split(' ').map(_.toDouble))
  }
def closest_assign(p: Vector[Double], centres: Array[Vector[Double]]): Int = {
    var bestIndex = 1
    var closest = Double.PositiveInfinity

    for (i <- 0 until centres.length) {
      val tempDist = squaredDistance(p, centres(i))

      if (tempDist < closest) {
        closest = tempDist
        bestIndex = i
      }
    }

    bestIndex
 }

val fileroot:String="/FileStore/tables/"
val file=sc.textFile(fileroot+"data.txt")
           .map(parse _)
           .cache()
val c1=sc.textFile(fileroot+"c1.txt")
         .map(parse _)
         .collect()

val c2=sc.textFile(fileroot+"c2.txt")
         .map(parse _)
         .collect()
val K=10
val MAX_ITER=20
var kPoints=c2

for(i<-0 until MAX_ITER){
    val closest = file.map(p => (closest_assign(p, kPoints), (p, 1)))

    val pointStats = closest.reduceByKey { case ((x1, y1), (x2, y2)) => (x1 + x2, y1 + y2) }

    val newPoints = pointStats.map { pair =>
        (pair._1, pair._2._1 * (1.0 / pair._2._2))
      }.collectAsMap()

     for (newP <- newPoints) {
        kPoints(newP._1) = newP._2
      }

  val tempDist = closest
    .map { x => squaredDistance(x._2._1, newPoints(x._1)) }
    .fold(0) { _ + _ }

     println(i+" time finished iteration (cost = " + tempDist + ")") 
}
```

In theory `tempDist` should become smaller and smaller as the program runs but in reality it goes the other way around.  Also I found `c1` and `c2` changes value after the `for(i<-0 until MAX_ITER)` loop. But `c1` and `c2` should be `val` values! Is the way I load `c1` and `c2` wrong? `c1` and `c2` are two different initial clusters for the data.

Comment: I'm not an expert in Scala, but could you hard-code some example values and print out what happens at each step? e.g. the cluster assignments and the cluster means. I suspect by printing out detailed debug information with a toy example, you could see what's going wrong.